# How to display array of JSON values in custom tableView cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to pass values inside for`(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)` which I get in NSLog to `[array addObject:[[SaveList alloc] initWithEmail:email withPhone:phone withDate:date withName:name]];`

Code is here

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@" http:// Some url "];

    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"\n\n JSON : %@, \n Error: %@", json, error);

    if(!error)
    {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSArray *myJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
       // NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        for(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON Dictionary = %@", jsonDictionary);

            NSString *name = jsonDictionary[@"Name"];
            NSString *date = jsonDictionary[@"Date"];
            NSString *email = jsonDictionary[@"Email"];
            NSString *phone = jsonDictionary[@"Phone"];
            NSLog(@"Name = %@", name);
            NSLog(@"Date = %@", date);
            NSLog(@"Email = %@", email);
            NSLog(@"Phone = %@", phone);
        }

    }
});



//Table implementation
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//**Get email, phone, date, name here**
    [array addObject:[[SaveList alloc] initWithEmail:email withPhone:phone withDate:date withName:name]];

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? Are you saying you want to know how to add the data in your array to the tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the objects as you receive them? Since this block of code will be executed asynchronously you could prepare your array, set your tableview and then execute the block where you fill your array and refresh the tableview.

Something like this:

```
// Prepare your array
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

// Set your tableview's datasource & delegate
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

// Fetch data asynchronously
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@" http:// Some url "];

    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"\n\n JSON : %@, \n Error: %@", json, error);

    if(!error)
    {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSArray *myJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
        NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:myJsonArray.count];

        for(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
        {

            NSString *name = jsonDictionary[@"Name"];
            NSString *date = jsonDictionary[@"Date"];
            NSString *email = jsonDictionary[@"Email"];
            NSString *phone = jsonDictionary[@"Phone"];


            //**Get email, phone, date, name here**
            [tmp addObject:[[SaveList alloc] initWithEmail:email 
                                                   withPhone:phone 
                                                    withDate:date 
                                                    withName:name]];
        }

        // Reload your tableview
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            array = tmp; // Or add them to your datasource array, whatever suits you...
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that the table view data source array should also not be modified on the background thread. You have to fetch into a separate array first. - Perhaps you meant that but it is not obvious from your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
set number of rows 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
[array count];
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    SavedList *savedList = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = savedList.name;

    }
    return cell;
    }

    I hope it will be helpful.
```

Comment: UITableViewCell is handled already. If I give @"Some Default String", it works. Now I need to pass the json values inside for loop to [array addObject:...]

Comment: you need to reload your table view then after adding object to array.Use [self.table view reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

//  U need to reload table view data whenever you add new object in it. It does work like a thread.

```
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     array = myJsonArray; 
     [self.tableView reloadData];
```